# Pass data from Bottom Sheet Dialog Fragment to Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation, android-bottomsheetdialog

I am using a BottomSheetDialogFragment class with Navigation Architecture component. I am following the Single activity pattern and therefore i have only one activity and several fragments. Below is my code.

BottomSheetDialogFragment.kt

```
class LogoBottomSheetFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

private var _binding: FragmentBottomSheetAccountLogoBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    _binding = FragmentBottomSheetAccountLogoBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

    return binding.root
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
}
```

And this is how i open the dialog in my navigation.xml from my main fragment:

```
    <dialog
    android:id="@+id/logoBottomSheetFragment"
    android:name="com.th3pl4gu3.locky.ui.main.add.account.LogoBottomSheetFragment"
    android:label="LogoBottomSheetFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_bottom_sheet_account_logo" />
```

Now i want to pass data FROM the bottom sheet to the main fragment.

Is there a proper way to do this? Can someone please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you read the [Returning a result documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#returning_a_result) that was recently added?

Comment: This is just perfect for my situation! Thank you so much for this. I was not aware of this workaround.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of [Navigation `2.3.0-alpha02`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.3.0-alpha02), Navigation has built in support for [Returning a result](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#returning_a_result) to a previous destination.

This works in two parts, your first fragment (the one wanting to receive the result) would use `navController.currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle` to get a reference to the `SavedStateHandle` associated with its `NavBackStackEntry` in the NavController. Then, it can `observe` a particular key to get a callback whenever that key changes.

The second fragment (the one delivering the result, i.e., your `LogoBottomSheetFragment`) would get a reference to that exact same `SavedStateHandle` by using `navController.previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle`. When that second fragment calls `set` on the `SavedStateHandle`, that result is then made available for the first fragment.

Note that there are some [DialogFragment specific considerations](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#additional_considerations) to keep in mind - because the previous fragment is `RESUMED` even when the `BottomSheetFragment` is being shown, the result will instantly be sent to your first fragment.